# How to convert a '' to NULL in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgreSQL table which accepts date in yyyy-mm-dd format and it is not accepting if the incoming date format is `''`(no date). There could be some instances when `''` gets passed as date. Could anyone help me write a function which checks if the incoming date is '' and then replaces it with NULL and then adds it to the db.

Comment: How would you add it to the database if the column is `not null`?

Comment: Apologies for not wording it better. I'd updated the text. what i meant was when a null date is passed.

Comment: can you show ur insert or update script  ?

Comment: This is a tcl command `update control_tracker set date='[regsub -all {\s} [string trim [regsub {\{.*} $whens1_12 ""]] "-" ]'`

Comment: Dates don't have "a format". So "accepts date in yyyy-mm-dd forma*" doesn't really make sense. Which data type exactly is that column?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`nullif()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF)

```
insert into the_table (the_date_column)
values (nullif(?, ''))
```

Or for an update

```
update the_table
  set the_date_column = nullif(?, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `case` expression to check for this. I'm using `:arg` to represent the inputting string - change it according to the programming language you're using:

```
INSERT INTO mytable
(my_date_col)
VALUES (CASE LENGTH(:arg) WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE TO_DATE(:arg, 'yyyy-mm-dd' END)
```